# SELECT FROM AS resulting in ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to run the following, I get error in oracle sql developer

```
SELECT VENDOR_CONTACT_LAST_NAME + ', ' + VENDOR_CONTACT_FIRST_NAME AS FULL_NAME
FROM VENDORS
```

The error is ORA-01722: invalid number. The two columns are both VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) and my searches suggest error may be do to trying to convert char to number, but I'm not doing that so I am very confused as the syntax looks right to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, your names are not numbers.  The correct syntax for string concatenation in Oracle is `||`:

```
SELECT (VENDOR_CONTACT_LAST_NAME || ', ' || VENDOR_CONTACT_FIRST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME
FROM VENDORS;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'm wondering why that isn't mentioned on this page though, as they do point out differences when they exist for the different languages, like you can see they showed how it's done with MySQL https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: beginners. The section on Data Types covers [Access, MySQL and SQL Server](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp): clearly W3School  think these are the databases most likely to be used by students. They aren't as explicit regarding syntax but I would assume the examples target target those three.

Comment: Makes sense, I just figured they did because I'd seen this earlier, which does mention it and show the different syntax https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp